# Publish Android library with external dependencies

Tags: java, android, maven, aar

I have an Android closed source module that will be be used as a library in other projects. It contains external dependencies.

To publish it, I'm creating a Maven artifact with the following gradle task:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

def coreAarFile = file('...build\\outputs\\aar\\android-sdk-release.aar')

artifacts {
    archives coreAarFile
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: "file://.\\mvn-repo")
        pom.project {
            groupId 'a.blabla'
            artifactId 'blabla-sdk'
            version "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

It generates the .aar file, the pom.xml, etc without problems.

Then I create a project that have a dependeny to my library declared. It works until it needs to access to the external dependencies, when throws a class not found exception.

How can I edit my gradle task to include external dependencies or at least a reference to them? They are published in mvnrepository.com and github.com.

Comment: Normally, the artifact IDs of your dependencies is added to the POM automatically. You might want to examine the POM that is deployed with your AAR and see whether the dependencies are identified in it.

Comment: I expected that my POM would contain a list of <dependency> elements. Unfortunately it does not.

Comment: Oh, wait. Why isn't `uploadArchives` in the real `build.gradle` file, where you are actually building the artifact? Your script appears to be trying to just publish a bare AAR. The dependency information normally is in the real `build.gradle` file, and that would get included if your `uploadArchives` is part of that script.

Comment: uploadArchives is in the build.gradle of my project (root directory). Should it be in the build.gradle of the module?

Comment: Yes. See, for example, [this one from one of my libraries](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity/blob/master/netsecurity/build.gradle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved uploadArchives to the build.gradle of the module and removed the artifacts element. It works!

Thanks to [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) for pointing to the right direction.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare. I was about to ask a new question when I found this one that seemed to be a match. I (finally) published a library to an S3 maven repository, but when I then tried to use it, it gave the fatal error "Didn't find class io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject". The difference is that I have dependencies for both io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid and io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava specified in the library module's build.gradle file already. Any idea why I would still get this error? (Should I ask a new question about this?)